# How to align or compare two string array?

Tags: c#

I have 2 string array for saving words of a text sentence and I have one string array for saving tags of words in first array. I want to get the tags of words in second array words according to first array tags.
both array may not have equal length and we have this rules for selecting tags:

```
//"a" and "b" suppose are words and "t" is a tag.
if tag1("a")="t" then tag2("a")=tag1("a")="t"
if tag1("a b")=="t" then tag2("a")=tag2("b")="t"
if tag1("a")=="t1" and tag1("b")=="t2" then tag2("a b")=tag1("a")="t1"
for other cases,which tag is selected is not important.
there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between elements in str1 and tag1.
In fact, if two element in str1 and str2 are same then the tags of them are same.
```

for example:

```
string[] str1={"this","is","a simple","text","for","example","."};
string[] str2={"this","is","a","simple text","for","example","."};
string[] tag1={"tt","ii","aa","ttt","ff","ee","pp"};

string[] tag2=new string[str2.length]

///getting tag2 array is the desired result:
string[] tag2={"tt","ii","aa","aa","ff","ee","pp"};
```

How to I can do it?

Thanks.

Comment: if you dont know the size of tag2, cant you use List ? also can the same word have 2 different tags if it appears multile times in the sentence ?

Comment: We know the size of tag2 is "str2.length" and all same words can have different tags or same tags in different places in the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code works for the given input and I am unable to foresee a case
>   where it might fail. It you come up with such a case, let me know. If this is not what you are looking for, this code should give you enough of an idea to get you started.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string[] str1 = { "this", "is", "a simple", "text", "for", "example", "." };
            //string[] str2 = { "this", "is", "a", "simple text", "for", "example", "." };
            //string[] tag1 = { "tt", "ii", "aa", "ttt", "ff", "ee", "pp" };
            //string[] tag2 = { "tt", "ii", "aa", "aa", "ff", "ee", "pp" };

            //string[] str1 = { "this", "is", "a simple", "text", "for", "this", "example", "." };
            //string[] str2 = { "this", "is", "a", "simple text", "for", "this example", "." };
            //string[] tag1 = { "tt", "ii", "aa", "ttt", "ff","tttt", "ee", "pp" };
            //string[] tag2 = { "tt", "ii", "aa", "aa", "ff", "tttt", "pp" };

            string[] str1 = { "this", "is", "a simple", "text", "for", "this", "example", "." };
            string[] str2 = { "this", "is", "a", "simple text", "for", "this example", "." };
            string[] tag1 = { "tt", "ii", "aa", "ttt", "ff", "tt", "ee", "pp" };
            string[] tag2 = { "tt", "ii", "aa", "aa", "ff", "tt", "pp" };

            Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Dictionary<string, int> wordIndexDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length; i++)
            {
                string word = str1[i];
                string tag = tag1[i];
                string[] words = word.Split();
                foreach (var item in words)
                {
                    int cnt = 1;
                    if (wordIndexDict.ContainsKey(item))
                    {
                        cnt = wordIndexDict[item];
                        wordIndexDict[item] = cnt + 1;
                        cnt = cnt + 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        wordIndexDict.Add(item, cnt);
                    }
                    map.Add(item + "_" + cnt, tag);

                }
            }

            wordIndexDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            List<string> output = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < str2.Length; i++)
            {
                string word = str2[i];
                string[] words = word.Split();

                int cnt = 1;
                if (wordIndexDict.ContainsKey(words[0]))
                {
                    cnt = wordIndexDict[words[0]];
                    wordIndexDict[words[0]] = cnt + 1;
                    cnt = cnt + 1;
                }
                else {
                    wordIndexDict.Add(words[0], cnt);
                }
                string key = words[0] + "_" + cnt;
                if (map.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    string tag = map[key];
                        output.Add(tag);
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in output)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. this code works with different words in str1 array, but  for same words in that we have  this error in "map.Add(item,tag)":
`An item with the same key has already been added.` for example if 
`str1 = { "this", "is", "a simple", "text", "for","a", "example", "." };`

Comment: can you give me an example where same word has multiple tags? please provide me with str1, str2, tag1 and expected tag 2. I fixed the code but need to test before posting it.

Comment: OK, `str1 = { "this", "is", "a simple", "text", "for", "this", "example", "." };str2 = { "this", "is", "a", "simple text", "for", "this example", "." };tag1 = { "tt", "ii", "aa", "ttt", "ff","tttt", "ee", "pp" }; tag2={  "tt", "ii", "aa", "aa", "ff", "tttt", "pp" };` An other example:
 `str1 = { "this", "is", "a simple", "text", "for", "this", "example", "." };str2 = { "this", "is", "a", "simple text", "for", "this example", "." };tag1 = { "tt", "ii", "aa", "ttt", "ff","tt", "ee", "pp" }; tag2={  "tt", "ii", "aa", "aa", "ff", "tt", "pp" };`

Comment: well it works for the given inputs. take a look. i update the post